# Formulário de inscrição personalizado

Tags: wordpress, microsoft-excel, formulário

Deparei-me com a necessidade de criar uma página com um formulário "simples", porém complexo em sua estrutura (acredito eu).

O que preciso fazer, é que ao criar um post no wordpress, onde o POST criado tenha uma PÁGINA única (formulário) de inscrição, da seguinte forma:

- POST > Curso de PHP Online / CATEGORIA > Cursos online

Ao final dela, tenha um LINK para uma página única ligada ao formulário para este curso, e ao final da data eu possa exportar em CSV ou EXCEL.

Eu tentei o contact form e o contact form DB, mas não consegui gerar formulários para cada post (curso) separado.

Alguém tem alguma ideia?

Answer (score 2):

Para montar os formulários, você vai precisar construir um plugin "na mão" (o que eu não recomendo a não ser em última necessidade), ou usar um plugin pronto. Pela sua descrição, eu acho que o **[Easy Contact Forms](https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-contact-forms/)** é uma boa pedida. Permite você montar o formulário que quiser com diversos campos. Ele manda por e-mail, exporta em planilha e salva em banco de dados. Acho que te atende. Ele só chatinho para configurar.

Depois que você criar os diversos formulários, você poderá usar a tag do próprio plugin para adicionar ele no seu post (curso). Cada formulário criado ganha um ID, aí basta você adicionar no seu post:

```
[easy_contact_forms fid = <id do formulario>]
```

Se você precisar de formulários mais dinâmicos, onde busca-se os valores de um *combobox* no banco de dados, por exemplo. Aí talvez você tenha que desenvolver.

Comment: Ricardo, com o Easy eu poderia criar um único formulário e usálo para vários posts? ou eu precisaria criar vários formulários?

Comment: Após pensar um pouco aqui, cheguei a essa conclusão, estaria certa?
se POST = CURSO DE PHP (Seria a categoria)
CURSO  = PHP + BANCO DE DADOS (Seria o curso)
A ideia seria usar o get_title pra puxar o curso, o problema é que não sei se é possível colocar isso dentro do Contact form 7 e como colocar... rrs

Comment: Respondendo ao primeiro comentário: Sim. Você pode colocar um mesmo formulários em quantos posts quiser. Respondendo ao segundo comentário: fica difícil te dar uma resposta sem saber direito o contexto. Mas um caminho seria assim: Categoria é curso e o Post seria uma especialização do curso. Vou fazer um exemplo com Java. Categoria seria "Cursos Java" e posso criar um post para cada especialidade / framework Java. Exemplo: Java Básico, JPA, JSF, Spring, Swing e por aí vai.